# Information closing?

Tags: word-usage

I came across the following sentence on the Internet, and I believe that "**closing**" doesn't collocate with "**information**" and that the whole sentence should be re-written.

> With the amount of information on the internet and some resources **changing, closing, or removed**, this document has been paired down from the original.

The following version is my suggestion:

> With the amount of Internet information **changing or removed**, and some resources **closing**, this document has been pared down from the original.

What do you guys think?

Answer (score 3):

"Closing" here has nothing to do with "information". It refers to "resources". The original sentence could be rephrased as:

> With some resources changing, closing, or removed and the amount of information on the internet...

With the exception of the homophone mistake made with "paired" (which you correctly changed to "pared"), the original sentence was correct.

Answer (score 1):

All three of "changing", "closing", and "removed" are adjectival participles that modify *resources*, not *information*.  So, while your edit is fine it does slightly alter the meaning.

It may not be clear how a resource can be "closed", or how that closing is different from being "removed", but I suspect it would be fine to anyone reading the document.  Of course, there are dozens of other, possibly better, ways to express the same idea.

Comment: Andrew. I am sorry but I disagree with you on this. The participle “closing” is meant to refer to “ resources”, but grammatically speaking, it can also be carried back to “information”, resulting in a clumsy sentence. I think the best way to write the original sentence is this: Owing to the constant change or removal of ever-increasing internet information, as well as the closing down of some resources, this document has been pared down from the original

Comment: @GrammarBoy  As you say, it's a clumsy sentence.  With sentences like this we take our best guess as to what the writer *meant* to say.  I suppose it's possible that they relate to "information" ... but that wouldn't be my first guess.

Answer (score 0):

The three qualifiers are referring to "resources" which works with "closing" in this case.